# Removing agent with specific parameter value in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

In a model I have two agent populations: `OriginalAgent` and `CopiedAgent`. They are different agent types. Each `CopiedAgent` is copied from a `OrginalAgent`, and they share the same values for `p_id`.

What I want to achieve is to remove an instance of `CopiedAgent` once `OriginalAgent` enters a final state in its statechart.

I have created a function `myfunction` that is called in the `Action` field of the final state in the statechart of `OriginalAgent`. The function errors when called, but it shows what I've tried:

```
int agent_index = 99999;
for(int i=0; i<main.CopiedAgent.size();i++){
    if(p_id == main.CopiedAgent(i).p_id){
        agent_index = main.CopiedAgent(i).p_id;
    }
}

if(my_biopsy_index != 99999)
main.remove_CopiedAgent(agent_index);
```

I believe the error originates from the loop, as the if-statement works as expected if I hardcode a specific index-value and comment out the loop.

Comment: can you specify the exact error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this maybe?

```
for(int i=0; i<main.CopiedAgent.size();i++){
    if(p_id == main.CopiedAgent(i).p_id){
        main.remove_CopiedAgent(i);
        break;
    }
}
```